# Typescript- How to get item in "nested" array using array of indexes

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have two arrays:
The first one looks something like this:

```js
interface IArrObj {
    name: string,
    objArr: IArrObj[]
}

const objArr: IArrObj[] = [
    {name: "obj0", objArr: [
        {name: "obj0_0", objArr: [
            {name: "obj0_0_0", objArr: []}
        ]},
        {name: "obj0_1", objArr: []}
    ]}, 
    {name: "obj1", objArr: []}
]
```

And another one like this:

```js
const indexArr = [0, 0, 0]
```

Now using the example `indexArr` I need to find the corresponding `arrObj` in the nested array.
Meaning: `arrObj[0].objArr[0].objArr[0]`.

I was able to put this into a function, but to me the way I solved it seems overcomplicated.

my solution:

```js
function getObjFromIndex(objArr: IArrObj[], indexArr: number[]): IArrObj {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < indexArr.length - 1; i++) {
        const currIndex = indexArr[i]
        objArr = objArr[currIndex].objArr
    }
    return objArr[indexArr[i]]
}
```

Is there another way to solve this?

([Live demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEkCCMYHkBGAVqgN7CoWpgIC2UAXKgM4QzgDmANOZQPZHYYjLDgKEA2gF1gAX2DAkvMC1T9Cg4YLFTUAXlTieFEtTqMARGoAM5zqoE5Ghyi9KmGqS0SsB9G3bUNAyNXFxNaDy9CXxjbe3VHA0k5UIpk7lS3CItrHwBGOMDEqRTKdNQQ8LNPNQKAhyEkuWkFJRVwABMoAA8gsABXGnxYHX0DKzsJ1CsWuH6wJAgQJVR2KAgxADEYXhp0MC7ugAoixpE8Iik7Tp6%20weGYKQBKTVEiUhCAG3XUEABuEJwXgwVBHEB6aZ-X6oAA8vwOtxwADpvmB2BAABaoAC0qDyUJAAGpCU8PplThDTuIbr0cNTJJIkacQqUKDB1v0YGB4oJqQjaY8QAzZPJFMpeN8Ubx2EcokFzKhCagAFIAZVwADkkSw2GiQHAAJ4nBpPJ6tcWSz7S2U0%20WK%20GHQRIwi8cBHADkdndpvNTAlUClMqiqCB8w6Fntaw2RG2u32h2NCRg135gieSPcTyAA))

Comment: Why do you want another way?

Comment: @Liam A more efficient/better way

Comment: Describe "better" and what does "efficient" actually mean to you? Both these terms are subjective

Comment: If it works, re-writing it because someone on the internet said they're version was "better" seems pointless TBH

Comment: @Liam Thought about it and you are right. Especially in this case where the solution is relatively simple and there aren't many options.

Answer (score 0):

(I agree with the comments) But here is a example with reduce.

```
const getObjFromIndex = (objArr: IArrObj[], indexArr: number[]) => 
indexArr.reduce((old, val, idx, arr) => (arr.length -1 === idx) ? old : old[val].objArr, objArr)[0];
```